# what is the difference between chanctx based drivers and non-chanctx based drivers?

Tags: linux, wifi, linux-device-driver, wireless

I am a newbie to linux device drivers. I have been writing driver for a WLAN device. While registering callbacks with mac80211, I found a few callbacks (OPTIONAL ones) regarding channel contexts. I just dont understand how they work?

Comment: What the hw do you working with? Have you checked if there is already a driver for a similar or exact chip?

Comment: we are working with a custom ip over some SoC.

Answer (score 1):

Please go through [this](https://www.linux.com/blog/linux-wireless-networking-short-walk) link to understand the significance of those structures.

Comment: I found the link useful. However, it doesn't really address channel contexts.